# Web service in visual studio 2005

Tags: .net, web-services, visual-studio-2005, asmx

Can we create webservice in visual studio 2005 .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just create a new Web Service project.

Comment: thank you,,Because now iam using visual studio 2008,,i am changing my system which will contain 2005 tats y

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you can only create an ASMX web service. Unfortunately, Microsoft now considers this to be legacy technology, and does not plan to fix any more bugs in it.

If you have a choice, you should upgrade to Visual Studio 2008 SP1, and create WCF services instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes you can.

Comment: thank you,,Because now iam using visual studio 2008,,i am changing my system which will contain 2005 tats y